# Why is it OK to drop articles in “Leopard Rock is fortress and home”?

Tags: articles, zero-article, omissibility

In episode one of the National Geographic documentary [*The Savage Kingdom*](https://www.natgeotv.com/za/shows/nationalgeographicwild/savage-kingdom), there is [this line](https://m.facebook.com/196008660929/videos/10154650735985930/?__so__=watchlist&__rv__=video_home_www_playlist_video_list) which you hear said (and see in the subtitles) there:

> Leopard Rock is fortress and home.

The line reads well, but I am just curious what the phenomenon here is whereby one is permitted to drop the article *a* or *the* before nouns *fortress* and *home* yet still remain grammatical.

If it were *fortress* alone, I think it should be:

> Leopard Rock is **a** fortress.

since *fortress* is a countable noun.

What makes it special and OK to omit the *a* or *the* here?

Comment: Good question. Is Leopard Rock a fortress, really, or is 'fortress' a metaphor for solid safety? Then it acts as such, but is not such. Not **a** fortress, but the concept of fortress: Leopard Rock is *home* (not a home) to many a creature.

Comment: What is the full context?

Comment: @alphabet It’s towards the end of [the clip](https://m.facebook.com/196008660929/videos/10154650735985930/?__so__=watchlist&__rv__=video_home_www_playlist_video_list) I linked to above.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You're right. I had a bunch of candidates and didn't manage to get them all up there. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following analysis. The construction is not unusual. For example, a google ngram search of "is friend and lover" shows many examples. Here is one:

[Priests in Love](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Priests_in_Love/eXl7SKEuTKUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is+friend+and+lover%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)
"*... but gradually they appear to be replacing his likeness with a new image of God who is friend and lover.*"

This example is revealing. In monotheisms such as the Catholic Church, God is seen as a defined entity, The (one and only) God. Such an entity must be described adjectivally: having the nature of friend and the nature of lover. There is no need to use the indefinite article to qualify the characteristics of a unique (definite) entity.

Similarly in your example, Leopard Rock is a definite entity so needs no indefinite article attached to its characteristics of being (or of having the nature of) fortress and home.

Comment: It’s curious how uncommon *BE fortress* is on its own—but it **does** occur. One can find language of a century ago like *Was this the face that had been fortress of those wraths?* Thrice that long ago John Wesley famously wrote *My rock and fortress is the Lord*, perhaps contributing to language in modern Christian writings like *Our Shield of Faith is fortress against the fiery darts of lust of the flesh and the eyes*. But it need not always be figurative, let alone Biblical, as seen in  *The Tower [of London] is, or has been, fortress, palace, and prison.* Yet that only works in a series.

Answer (score 1):

> Leopard rock is fortress and home.

As, with the exception of a few special contexts, all singular nouns must be modified by a determiner of some sort.

"Fortress" is a concept.

It follows that "fortress" is an uncountable noun.

In this case it means "Leopard rock is *of the nature of a member of the homogeneous class of things that are described by the noun* "fortress".

This distinguishes it from

a fortress = a single example of a fortress.

The fortress = a specific fortress.

Sir Henry's fortress = a fortress under the control of Sir Henry.

Etc.

which are direct descriptions of the building, rather than the nature of the building.